# unable to install confluent-kafka python module on alpine 3.13.5

Tags: python, docker, gitlab-ci-runner, alpine-linux

I am trying to install `confluent-kafka` on a `alpine-3.13.5`. Basically i am trying the same in `docker in docker` - https://hub.docker.com/_/docker as part of my `gitlab runner`.

This is how my `.gitlab-ci.yml` looks like

```
default:
  image:
    name: docker:19.03
    entrypoint:
      - '/usr/bin/env'
      - 'PATH=/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin'
  tags:
    - general
  services:
    - docker:dind

before_script:
  - apk update
  - apk add gcc libc-dev libffi-dev librdkafka-dev
  - apk add --update --no-cache python3 python3-dev && ln -sf python3 /usr/bin/python
  - python3 -m ensurepip
  - pip3 install --no-cache --upgrade pip setuptools
  - pip install poetry
  - poetry install
  - source `poetry env info --path`/bin/activate
```

Now one of my python dependency is `confluent-kafka==1.8.2` , which is failing during `poetry install` . I am getting below error

```
building 'confluent_kafka.cimpl' extension
  creating build/temp.linux-x86_64-cpython-38
  creating build/temp.linux-x86_64-cpython-38/tmp
  creating build/temp.linux-x86_64-cpython-38/tmp/tmphywbhg0_
  creating build/temp.linux-x86_64-cpython-38/tmp/tmphywbhg0_/confluent-kafka-1.8.2
  creating build/temp.linux-x86_64-cpython-38/tmp/tmphywbhg0_/confluent-kafka-1.8.2/src
  creating build/temp.linux-x86_64-cpython-38/tmp/tmphywbhg0_/confluent-kafka-1.8.2/src/confluent_kafka
  creating build/temp.linux-x86_64-cpython-38/tmp/tmphywbhg0_/confluent-kafka-1.8.2/src/confluent_kafka/src
  gcc -Wno-unused-result -Wsign-compare -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O3 -Wall -fomit-frame-pointer -g -fno-semantic-interposition -fomit-frame-pointer -g -fno-semantic-interposition -fomit-frame-pointer -g -fno-semantic-interposition -DTHREAD_STACK_SIZE=0x100000 -fPIC -I/tmp/tmpvzpv4nqv/.venv/include -I/usr/include/python3.8 -c /tmp/tmphywbhg0_/confluent-kafka-1.8.2/src/confluent_kafka/src/Admin.c -o build/temp.linux-x86_64-cpython-38/tmp/tmphywbhg0_/confluent-kafka-1.8.2/src/confluent_kafka/src/Admin.o
  In file included from /tmp/tmphywbhg0_/confluent-kafka-1.8.2/src/confluent_kafka/src/Admin.c:17:
  /tmp/tmphywbhg0_/confluent-kafka-1.8.2/src/confluent_kafka/src/confluent_kafka.h:66:2: error: #error "confluent-kafka-python requires librdkafka v1.6.0 or later. Install the latest version of librdkafka from the Confluent repositories, see http://docs.confluent.io/current/installation.html"
     66 | #error "confluent-kafka-python requires librdkafka v1.6.0 or later. Install the latest version of librdkafka from the Confluent repositories, see http://docs.confluent.io/current/installation.html"
        |  ^~~~~
  error: command '/usr/bin/gcc' failed with exit code 1
  
  at /usr/lib/python3.8/site-packages/poetry/installation/chef.py:152 in _prepare
      148│ 
      149│                 error = ChefBuildError("\n\n".join(message_parts))
      150│ 
      151│             if error is not None:
    → 152│                 raise error from None
      153│ 
      154│             return path
      155│ 
      156│     def _prepare_sdist(self, archive: Path, destination: Path | None = None) -> Path:
Note: This error originates from the build backend, and is likely not a problem with poetry but with confluent-kafka (1.8.2) not supporting PEP 517 builds. You can verify this by running 'pip wheel --use-pep517 "confluent-kafka (==1.8.2)"'.
```

Comment: I am able to install `confluent-kafka == 1.3.0` but not `1.8.2` . So I am guessing its an issue with `librdkafka` which is not supporting higher version of `confluent-kafka`. Since I am not mentioning any version while installing , how can I control that.

Comment: Then it leave you to either this: [Installing librdkafka using vcpkg](https://github.com/confluentinc/librdkafka#installing-librdkafka-using-vcpkg), but it seems [the tools does not work on Alpine](https://github.com/microsoft/vcpkg/issues/21218), or that: [Build from source](https://github.com/confluentinc/librdkafka#build-from-source); but you might have no luck still because Alpine is based on musl and not glibc. If all fails, then you'd probably best going with a more "common" Linux distribution.

Comment: Luckily `confluent-kafka == 1.5.0` worked for me . I was having  `librdkafka-dev-1.5.3-r1` for my `alpine-3.13.5` , which supports max `confluent-kafka == 1.5.0`. For `confluent-kafka == 1.8.2` I need `librdkafka-dev >=1.6.0` which my existing `alpine` version doesn't support.

Comment: I see, that you did not add "librdkafka" next to "librdkafka-dev". The error message states that exactly. Can you confirm it works, when adding it?